# Android App Static Shortcut with Navigation Library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-appshortcut

My app has one static shortcut, and I'm using the navigation architecture component.

I'm using the following implementation but it does not work on Android 9.

In my MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setupToolbar()
    setupNavigationDrawer()

    checkPermissions()

    if (intent.action == MoneyBook.SHORTCUT_ACTION_ADD_BOOKENTRY) {
        findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).popBackStack(R.id.action_entriesFragment_to_newBookEntryFragment, false)
    }
}
```

shortcuts.xml:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shortcut_addbookentry"
        android:shortcutId="shortcut_addbookentry"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/shortcut_addbookentry_label_short"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_addbookentry_label_short">

        <intent
            android:action="at.guger.moneybook.action.ADD_BOOKENTRY"
            android:targetClass="at.guger.moneybook.activity.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="at.guger.moneybook.dev" />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

When debugging the app, I noticed that the `findNavController(...)` method is called, but nothing happens on the screen.

Further, I do not override `onStart(...)` or `onResume(...)`.

Is there any given way to implement app shortcuts with navigation component or am I doing something terribly wrong here?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `popBackStack()` goes back - do you mean to call `navigate()` instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Navigation does not support deep linking by `intent.action` alone. However, you *can* add an `android:data` element to your `<intent>` element and then [add a implicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) to your navigation graph. By doing this, you won't have to write any specific code for handling the Intent.

For example, change your `shortcuts.xml` to add the `android:data` attribute:

```
<intent
        android:action="at.guger.moneybook.action.ADD_BOOKENTRY"
        android:targetClass="at.guger.moneybook.activity.MainActivity"
        android:targetPackage="at.guger.moneybook.dev"
        android:data="moneybook://add_book_entry" />
```

and in your navigation graph XML file, add a `<deepLink>` element for the same URL:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/add_book_entry_fragment"
  android:name=".AddBookEntryFragment">
  <deepLink app:uri="moneybook://add_book_entry" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's absolutely the cleanest solution!